# How to install Google-Maps-iOS-Utils in swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm trying to install Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (for clustering) with pod install and I get the error :

> target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries...

According to google docs I created my bridging header and added:

```
import Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h
```

But of course it cannot find Google-Maps-iOS-Utils...

Txs for help !

link to google doc
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/setup

Answer (score 0):

Fixed adding manually...

Here fore the steps:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got your Podfile, you can simply type:

```
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
```

Into your podfile and then run `pod install` into your folder directory on Terminal.